# Maven pom.xml files getting deleted

Tags: eclipse, maven

My pom.xml file of child modules get deleted automatically in eclipse but the parent pom remains..can anyone put some light into the matter?

I have tried locating the file manually using search but to no use.

Comment: What do you mean with `get deleted automatically`? Who deletes them? Did you trigger anything? Did you comment out their modules in the parent pom?

Comment: No..I haven't made any changes to the parent file..but sometimes after refreshing, it shows that the child pom is missing..

Comment: The same thing just happened to me.